# Excel: Calculate effective value based on previous rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

So, I want the effective value to as such. Whenever a new value is added, it is to be incremented by 20% until it reaches a maximum of 100%. For eg, until 5th day, the effective value was 3, same as the initial value. Since day 5 has a value 2, effective value henceforth will be incremented daily by 20%. In day 8, there's a new value 5 being added. So, the effective value will be 3 + 2 * 0.8 + 5 * 0.2 = 5.6 and so on.

Initial value = 3

| Days | Value | Effective Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 3 |
| 2 |  | 3 |
| 3 |  | 3 |
| 4 |  | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 3.4 |
| 6 |  | 3.8 |
| 7 |  | 4.2 |
| 8 | 5 | 5.6 |
| 9 |  | 7 |
| 10 |  | 8 |
| 11 |  | 9 |
| 12 |  | 10 |
| 13 |  | 10 |
| 14 |  | 10 |

I tried using rows formula but I can't find a logic that works.

Comment: Can you please show us the formulas you have tried?

Comment: Maybe not a perfect answer but might be good enough: sum the previous five cells in 'Values', divide this by five, then add this to the previous 'Effective Value'. This gets a bit messy near the top, but start at the bottom with (assuming your bottom right cell is C15): =C14+SUM(B11:B15)/5 . Please let me know if that's not clear.

Comment: In `C3` `=C2+(0.2*SUM(INDEX(B:B,MAX(1,ROW()-4)):B3))` while `C2` is initial value